# What does "something got me like" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms, slang

For example:
"Instagram stories got me like, you all need to listen to better music".

Comment: This use of ***like*** is very informal, often with strong "uneducated" overtones. But your example doesn't even seem to be from a native speaker, since it would be extremely unusual to include the article in *listen to **a** better music*.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Comment: “____ got me like” seems to be contemporary slang or an internet meme. Google [ ["got me like" meme](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22got%20me%20like%22%20meme) ], and also check out the 2015 *Halvorsen* track “She Got Me Like”. I wouldn't want to guess which came first. Based on this very hasty research I'd paraphrase “Instagram stories *make me feel* ...”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means 'Makes me think and/or do'. Such as in the example, this person is reading through Instagram and posts and has come to the conclusion that the music they listen to is bad, and thinks (or has him like) they should listen to better music.

For example, if someone was to say "Your outfit got me like someone punched me in the gut" as a way to say someone's outfit was ridiculous. The phrase is also widely used to compare your feeling to another similar feeling, but something greatly exaggerated. Firstly, the 'like someone punched me in the gut' is comparing how the person stating the sentence is laughing so hard they cannot breathe, similar to being punched in the gut. the 'got me like' is used as a comparison to another exaggerated situation.

Comment: Hello, Dshdsq. It probably does, but a supporting reference and caveat about acceptability in various registers would make this the sort of answer ELU prefers.

Comment: I'll remember that

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't get it completely. Can you explain it with more examples?

Comment: Sure, in addition, if someone was to say "Your outfit got me like someone punched me in the gut" as a way to say someone's outfit was ridiculous. The phrase is also widely used to compare your feeling to another similar feeling, but something greatly exaggerated. Firstly, the 'like someone punched me in the gut' is comparing how the person stating the sentence is laughing so hard they cannot breathe, similar to being punched in the gut. the 'got me like' is used as a comparison to another exaggerated situation.

Comment: So "got me like" is always used for exaggeration?

Comment: This answer is, like, *misleading*. OP's specific context is effectively using ***like*** as an almost meaningless "discourse marker". It doesn't carry any significant sense of comparison - what the speaker means is *Instagram stories got me **thinking** [that] you all need to listen to better music*.

Comment: Usually @Sartist

Comment: What does "got me like" mean in this example? :
a picture of a room with many cloths all over it with caption "Packing got me like"

Comment: Saying that packing has them frantically attempting to gather all their stuff with a (possibly) exaggerated image of their belonging scattered everywhere. In some situations (such as possibly this one), the situation pictured or said doesn't need to be exaggerated, but most usages of the term include hyperbole of the situation the person is in